# Add HTML to custom post type edit page

Tags: wp-admin, hooks, html

I have searching for adding HTML to a CPT edit page on the admin side.
On the internet I see a lot about metaboxes but not about adding your own HTML stuff.

Is there somebody who knows more about this?

Comment: Where do you want to add it? Are you referring to the classic editor or the block editor?

Comment: I want add my own HTML stuff at the bottom of the page type edit page. I use the classic editor.

Comment: ACF is a great plugin to extend editing options - and free.